# How to display Employee Attendance Data in Crosstab Format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an attendance table like this

[image]

now i want results like this in sql server management.. results should like this one

[image]

Comment: Do this in your presentation later. And where did 9:01 come from? And where did 9:25 go? It was replaced with the values from the other user? What have you tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your desired results do not make sense.  It looks like the values are made up.

Comment: I think he just copy-pasted it incorrectly.

Comment: Make it Simple 
1 2 3 4 5 is no of days
and there are three columns time in , time out , totalhours
and all of these i need in one column as per day.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is exactly what you want, but it might give you an idea how to do it:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(EmpID INT, InDate DATE, InTime TIME, OutTime TIME);
GO
INSERT INTO #t(EmpID, InDate, InTime, OutTime) VALUES
(189,'2013-12-01','9:14','9:14'),
(189,'2013-12-01','18:15','18:15'),
(89,'2013-12-01','9:25','9:25'),
(89,'2013-12-01','18:15','18:15');
GO
;WITH s AS (SELECT EmpID
    , InTime = CAST(InTime AS DATETIME)
    , OutTime = CAST(OutTime AS DATETIME)
    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY InTime) 
    , rid = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EmpID DESC, InTime)
    FROM #t)
, d AS (
    SELECT r1.EmpID, rn = 10000, rid = r2.rid
        , InTime = '  ' + CAST(CAST(r2.InTime - r1.InTime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5))
        , OutTime = '  ' + CAST(CAST(r2.OutTime - r1.OutTime AS TIME) AS CHAR(5))
    FROM s AS r1 INNER JOIN s AS r2
    ON r1.EmpID = r2.EmpID AND r1.rn = 1 AND r2.rn = 2)
, r AS (SELECT EmpID = IIF(rn = 1,CAST(EmpID AS VARCHAR),'')
    , InTime = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,InTime,0),7)
    , OutTime = RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,OutTime,0),7)
    , rn, rid FROM s UNION ALL 
    SELECT '', InTime, OutTime  , rn, rid FROM d
)
SELECT EmpID, InTime, OutTime FROM r
ORDER BY rid, rn
```

Comment: You are smart, but I fear your question without explanation will only confuse the OP

Comment: It might, but if he learns how to do it, he'll appreciate it.

Comment: Make it Simple 1 2 3 4 5 is no of days and there are three columns time in , time out  and totalhours so now i want all of these in one column as per day. as in given picture...

Comment: Have you tried the script? It produces exactly content you've provided. If it does not work for you you have to write better description of your problem.
If you want to keep it simple just use Excel.